# Question about limit of an integral of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $ f$ be a real-valued continuous function defined for all $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$, such that $f(0) = 1$, $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 2$ and $f(1) = 3$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \! f(x^n) \, \mathrm{d}x $$  exists and compute this limit.

I try to use mean value theorems and Stone–Weierstrass theorem, it goes nowhere. I really appreciate if someone helps me.

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f(x^n)$?

Comment: thank you Sir for type correction.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is continuous and defined on a closed interval, it is bounded, i.e. there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)\leqslant M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore the constant function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ with $g(x)=M$ is a dominating function, i.e. $|f(x)|\leqslant g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. So by dominated convergence,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x^n)\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x^n)\ \mathsf dx. $$
Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x^n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n\right)$, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = \begin{cases} 0,& 0\leqslant x < 1\\ 1,& x=1.\end{cases}$$
As $f(x^n)\to f(0)$ almost everywhere, the integral is equal to
$$\int_0^1 f(0)\ \mathsf dx = 1. $$

Comment: thank you Sir for this beautiful solution.

Comment: You're welcome. How fitting your name is "henri," that was Lebesgue's first name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-(2x+1)$. Then $g(0)=g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=g(1)=0$ and $g$ is continuous.

By the Weierstrass approximation theorem it follows that: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}g(x^n)\,dx = g(0) = 0$$
hence:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(x^n)\,dx = 1.$$

Comment: And yet another beauty. You all amaze me while allowing to look at somehow different points of views on same question and same thing. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $|f(x)|\le M$ for $ x\in [0,1].$ Let $0<r<1.$ Then

$$\tag 1 |\int_0^1 f(x^n)\ dx - f(0)| = |\int_0^1 (f(x^n)- f(0))\ dx|$$ $$ \le \int_0^1 |f(x^n)- f(0)|\ dx \le \int_0^r |f(x^n)- f(0)|\ dx + 2M(1-r).$$

The last integral is $\le r \cdot \sup_{[0,r^n]} |f(u)-f(0)|.$ Because $r^n \to 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0,$ we see this integral $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Thus the $\limsup_{n\to \infty}$ of $(1)$ is $\le 2M(1-r).$ Since $r$ is arbitrarily close to $1,$ the $\limsup$ is $0,$ which is the desired result.

Note that we only used the continuity of $f$ at $0.$ Thus the result holds for any Riemann integrable $f$ on $[0,1]$ that is continuous at $0.$

Comment: And here again another point of view, magnificent solution Sir, thank you immensely.